# Trouble cabal installing http-conduit

Tags: haskell, cabal

When I run `cabal install http-conduit`, I get the following:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: base-4.12.0.0/installed-4.1... (user goal)
[__1] trying: ghc-8.6.5/installed-8.6... (user goal)
[__2] next goal: process (user goal)
[__2] rejecting: process-1.6.7.0 (constraint from user target requires
==1.6.6.0)
[__2] rejecting: process-1.6.6.0 (conflict: ghc =>
process==1.6.5.0/installed-1.6...)
[__2] rejecting: process-1.6.5.1, process-1.6.5.0/installed-1.6...,
process-1.6.5.0, process-1.6.4.0, process-1.6.3.0, process-1.6.2.0,
process-1.6.1.0, process-1.6.0.0, process-1.5.0.0, process-1.4.3.0,
process-1.4.2.0, process-1.4.1.0, process-1.4.0.0, process-1.3.0.0,
process-1.2.3.0, process-1.2.2.0, process-1.2.1.0, process-1.2.0.0,
process-1.1.0.2, process-1.1.0.1, process-1.1.0.0, process-1.0.1.5,
process-1.0.1.4, process-1.0.1.3, process-1.0.1.2, process-1.0.1.1,
process-1.0.0.0 (constraint from user target requires ==1.6.6.0)
[__2] fail (backjumping, conflict set: ghc, process)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: process, base, ghc
```

I'm running cabal v3.0.0.0 and ghc v8.6.5

I'm quite new to the Haskell ecosystem, so any help I could get would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a dependency conflict, one package requires a different version than the package you are trying to install. This can be very difficult to solve for new users.

If you are new to Haskell and want to start using dependencies from [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/), the centralized package archive for Haskell, I recommend using stack ([install instructions](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/) and [basic workflow](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/). `stack` is a tool built on top of `cabal` that includes a curated list of package versions that are compatible. It should make it easier for you to get started.